# Prevent ListView insertion animation execution on existing entries

Tags: java, android, listview, animation, android-listview

I have watched Android developer's videos on animating ListView insertion and deletion on YouTube. These have had very complex code in them and I tried searching for something else and found this.

http://karnshah8890.blogspot.fi/2013/04/listview-animation-tutorial.html

It has pretty simple implementation that works in most parts. My problem is that when I insert a new item in the ArrayList that is supplied to the ArrayAdapter, all the existing elements get reinserted due to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`... I think. When I insert an entry in the ListView, how do I prevent all the entries from getting animated again? I just want the new one to animate in.

I use my ListView in the code this way:

```
toggles = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleListView);

adapter = new ToggleListAdapter(getActivity(), toggleTasks);
toggles.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When a new item is inserted, I update the ArrayList (`toggleTasks`) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

```
toggleTasks.add(task);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is my `getView()` method from the ArrayAdapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ToggleTask task = toggles.get(position);

    String startActionName = "";
    String finishActionName = ""; 
    int imageDrawableId = -1;

    // Deleted the part where I get the values for those three variables above

    final Holder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mute_toggles_toggle_view, null);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.startAction = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startAction);
        holder.finishAction = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.finishAction);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.image.setImageResource(imageDrawableId);
    holder.startAction.setText(startActionName);
    holder.finishAction.setText(finishActionName);

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.listview_push_left_in); // Third animation example on the site linked earlier
    animation.setDuration(500);
    convertView.startAnimation(animation);
    animation = null;

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Suppose there 5 visible children at present in your ListView at positions 0, 1, 2, 3, 4th. What will happen, if I just delete the child at 2th position?

Answer (score 1):

in the ArrayAdatper class add a global integer (I'll call it changedIndex) and create getter and setters for it. Then before you add an item to the list say adapter.setChangedIndex(index) (whatever you name your setter). You are essentially telling it ahead of time which one you want to animate.

Change this in getView

```
if(changedIndex == position){
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.listview_push_left_in); // Third animation example on the site linked earlier
    animation.setDuration(500);
    convertView.startAnimation(animation);
    animation = null;
}
```

then change

```
toggleTasks.add(task);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to

```
toggleTasks.add(task);
toggles.getPosition(task);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

*I haven't checked any of this code but I believe it should work

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to `animate` only the `last item` inserted, then before animating check if it is last item in the `List`.

```
if (position == getCount() - 1) {

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.listview_push_left_in); // Third animation example on the site linked earlier
    animation.setDuration(500);
    convertView.startAnimation(animation);
    animation = null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ListViewAnimations](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations) library. After setting up your `ListView` and `ListAdapter` like this:

```
MyListAdapter mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, getItems());
SwingRightInAnimationAdapter swingRightInAnimationAdapter = new SwingRightInAnimationAdapter(mAdapter);

// Assign the ListView to the AnimationAdapter and vice versa
swingRightInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(getListView());
getListView().setAdapter(swingRightInAnimationAdapter);
```

Call `AnimationAdapter.setShouldAnimateFromPosition(int position)` somewhat like this:

```
swingRightInAnimationAdapter.setShouldAnimateFromPosition(swingRightInAnimationAdapter.getCount());
swingRightInAnimationAdapter.add(myItem);
```

Have a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/wiki/Appearance-Animations) for more information about how to use the library.

Comment: I am using your awesome [ListViewAnimations](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/) library by including it in the gradle file. Everything is working fine but there is no `setShouldAnimateFromPosition` method for AnimationAdapter which I need to use. Is it removed any reason? Is there any other way instead?
Thanks.

Comment: @neelamc23 use `getViewAnimator().set...`.